# Method orWhere does not exist. Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3

BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method orWhere does not exist.

```
    $category = $categories->where('Node_ID', (explode('.', $cat{$title_id})[0]))
        ->orWhere('Node_Path', $cat->{$category_name})
        ->first();
```

If I try without "orWhere" works, if I use it, throws an Error. Someone knows where is the mistake?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are trying to use `orWhere` on collections, thats why its showing you the error. You should use this on model like this (taking `Category` as a Model):

```
$category = Category::where('Node_ID', (explode('.', $cat{$title_id})[0]))
                     ->orWhere('Node_Path', $cat->{$category_name})
                     ->first();
```

> See Laravel Docs for [`orWhere()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_orWhere)

Hope this helps!